# Is there a way to reset smbclient settings to the default?

Tags: samba

I think i made a few bugs in config settings of smb.conf and i want to get my original network settings back..is there any way for that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get your *edited* smb.conf back and didn't backup before I fear there is no possibility. You can take a look at /etc/samba and watch for files like "smb.conf~", "smb.conf.bak" or something like this ...

An example smb.conf is to find at /usr/share/samba/. Replace your misconfigured file by

```
sudo cp /usr/share/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf
sudo initctl restart smbd
```

And from now backup your files before editing:

```
sudo cp /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf.backup_120418
```

or something like this.

Comment: Also consider using something like etckeeper to keep the revisions you make to these files handy.